# How to make jScrollPane contents draggable

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane to create a "timeline" effect within a horizontally scrolling window.

Using jQuery UI, I've applied "draggable" to the content , thus making it draggable.

The two plugins are totally separate though, so I'm coming across issues such as jScrollPane not knowing where jQuery UI dropped the draggable element.

**Is there a way to create this mouse dragging functionality, within jScrollPane rather than jQuery UI? It has a scrollbar which could surely be reused in some way for this purpose?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work around this issue by making jQuery UI "draggable" let jScrollPane know when the content panel has been dropped:

```
// Make timeline draggable
jspPane.draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    cursor: 'e-resize',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.position.left );
        api.scrollToX(Math.abs(offsetXPos), false);
    },

    // Stop dragging at edges
    drag: function( event, ui) {

        var pos = ui.position.left;

        if (pos < -timelineWidth + 900 ) {
            jspPane.css('left', -timelineWidth + 900 );
            return false;
        }

        if ( pos >= 0 ) {
            jspPane.css('left', 0);
            return false;
        }

    }
});
```

Therefore, I can continue to use jQuery UI for the draggable content panel.

Making jScrollPanel natively provide this functionality would be preferred though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload a sample at http://jsfiddle.net with complete HTML, CSS and JavaScript used?  We can then take a look to see what can be done.

Comment: I can easily explain what I'm after. The demo of jScollPane can be found here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

I'm looking to make the contents draggable with the mouse, rather than just the scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for those demos! The items in the content panel don't need to be draggable though, the actual content panel needs to be draggable thus scrolling the jScrollPane.

Comment: Did any one of those demos capture what you were looking the achieve?  Please do let me know which one was the closest to your requirements.  I had never tried to use these two plugins together but it was a good exercise for me to try them together.

Comment: I'm afraid not, as I say whatever is in the content panel doesn't need to be draggable, the actual content panel itself needs to be draggable, thus scrolling the window when dragged.

Comment: Any luck with this? I´m looking for a panel/draggable timeline plugin where I can drag the content boxes along a timeline to update a datetime attribute with knockoutJS. Content box should be a div with any UI/HTML contents in it. Use should be as a planning scheme... (think MS Project)